# Bulbs and brightness

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage

This may seem like a really basic question, but why do some bulbs glow brighter than others. Is it the increased power rating?

Also I don't understand whether increasing the current or increasing the voltage will make the bulb grow brighter, or is it both?

Answer (score 1):

Your first paragraph answers your own question. It **is** as basic as you say, the more power you put through the filament of the lamp, as long as it is not over the wattage rating of the bulb, the brighter it will get. Putting 200 watts through a 60 watt bulb will be wasting your money, it will blow the filament in no time.

Electrical power is measured in watts, which is the rate of energy use, in joules per second. The electrical  bulbs you buy are rated by wattage, and the power they use is the voltage multiplied by the current.

Extract and image from: [Electrical Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power)

> Electric power, like mechanical power, is the rate of doing work, measured in watts, and represented by the letter $P$. The term wattage is used colloquially to mean "electric power in watts." The electric power in watts produced by an electric current $I$ consisting of a charge of $Q$ coulombs every $t$ seconds passing through an electric potential (voltage) difference of $V$ is:
>
> $${\displaystyle P={\text{work done per unit time}}={\frac {VQ}{t}}=VI\,}$$
>
> where
>
> $Q$ is electric charge in coulombs
>
> $T$ is time in seconds
>
> $I $ is electric current in amperes
>
> $V$ is electric potential or voltage in volts

[image]

If you are interested, you can find a full description here: [Hyperphysics Electrical Power](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elepow.html)